# What are good resources to study crystallographic defects in different dimensional systems and their topological dimensionality?

Tags: reference-request, crystal-structure, condensed-matter, defects, topological-insulators

I wonder if there are any books or resources that may address one or more of the following questions:

- What kinds of defects are important for topology? Especially crystallographic defects.
- How do they relate to the defect topological dimension?
- How do they change in different crystal dimensions?

Answer (score 6):

Arkadiy Simonov and Andrew Goodwin have a nice review out on the arXiv regarding designing disorder into materials, that can elicit unique topological states [1], and there is are some older reviews discussing specifically crystallography [2,3]. For a more robust mathematical treatment, this paper focuses on abstraction with a set of good physical examples [4].

1. [arXiv:1912.00366](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.00366)
2. [D. A. Keen, A. L. Goodwin, *Nature* **521**, 303–309 (2015).](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature14453)
3. [T. R. Welberry, T. Weber
   *Crystallography Reviews*  **22**,  2-78  (2016)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/0889311X.2015.1046853)
4. [N. D. Mermin, *Rev. Mod. Phys.*  **51**,  591-648 (1979).](https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/RevModPhys.51.591)